# Settings for new environment

Tags: environments, technical-environment

I'm creating a new document based on another being successful, but it's too long to use as a MWE.

Anyway, I'm trying to create a new environment, but it's missing something I do not know what to look for.

This new environment is to get something like this:

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}

\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}

\RequirePackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}

%-------Etapa Box------------
\newmdenv[skipabove=7pt,
skipbelow=7pt,
rightline=false,
leftline=true,
topline=false,
bottomline=false,
backgroundcolor=ocre!10,
linecolor=ocre,
innerleftmargin=5pt,
innerrightmargin=5pt,
innertopmargin=5pt,
innerbottommargin=5pt,
leftmargin=0cm,
rightmargin=0cm,
linewidth=4pt]{eBox}
%------------------------------------------

%-------Hyperref and BookMark-------
\hypersetup{hidelinks,backref=true,pagebackref=true,hyperindex=true,colorlinks=false,breaklinks=true,urlcolor= ocre,bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=false,pdftitle={Title},pdfauthor={Author}}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\bookmarksetup{
open,
numbered,
addtohook={%
\ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=0 % chapter
\bookmarksetup{bold}%
\fi
\ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=-1 % part
\bookmarksetup{color=ocre,bold}%
\fi
}
}

\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{%
  \texorpdfstring{}{\chaptername\space}\arabic{chapter}%
  \texorpdfstring{}{: }%
}
% Section numbers without prefix or the place for adding a prefix
% "Section".
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{%
  \arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}%
}
%------------------------------------------

%----------New Theorem---------------
\newtheorem{etapaT}{Passo}[section]
%------------------------------------------

%-------New Environment------------
\newenvironment{etapa}{\begin{eBox}\begin{etapaT}}{\hfill{\color{ocre}\tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}\end{etapaT}\end{eBox}}     
%------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Informações}
\section{Conversa informal}

    \begin{etapa}
Texto
    \end{etapa}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think, you should use the more powerful `tcolorbox` package instead of `mdframed` here. Besides that, your example does not compile, and `\RequirePackage` is 'reserved' for packages rather than documents; but in total, I don't understand what you're after here

Comment: Your MWE is almost fine, I would say. You should replace `\RequirePackage` with `\usepackage`. Then, in order to use `\blacksquare`, you have to load the package `amssymb`. Finally, you could shift the black square a bit, maybe with `\raisebox{0.166em}{\blacksquare}`.

Comment: I changed the New Theorem by removing Chapter and inserting the section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I use `tcolorbox` instead of `mdframed` and apply one single environment for this.

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}

\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}



\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}


%-------Etapa Box------------
\newmdenv[skipabove=7pt,
skipbelow=7pt,
rightline=false,
leftline=true,
topline=false,
bottomline=false,
backgroundcolor=ocre!10,
linecolor=ocre,
innerleftmargin=5pt,
innerrightmargin=5pt,
innertopmargin=5pt,
innerbottommargin=5pt,
leftmargin=0cm,
rightmargin=0cm,
linewidth=4pt]{eBox}
%------------------------------------------

%-------Hyperref and BookMark-------
\hypersetup{hidelinks,backref=true,pagebackref=true,hyperindex=true,colorlinks=false,breaklinks=true,urlcolor= ocre,bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=false,pdftitle={Title},pdfauthor={Author}}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\bookmarksetup{
open,
numbered,
addtohook={%
\ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=0 % chapter
\bookmarksetup{bold}%
\fi
\ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=-1 % part
\bookmarksetup{color=ocre,bold}%
\fi
}
}

\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{%
  \texorpdfstring{}{\chaptername\space}\arabic{chapter}%
  \texorpdfstring{}{: }%
}
% Section numbers without prefix or the place for adding a prefix
% "Section".
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{%
  \arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}%
}
%------------------------------------------


\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=section]{etapa}[1][]{
  enhanced,
  attach title to upper={},
  coltitle={ocre},
  fonttitle={\bfseries},
  title={Passo \thetcbcounter:\ },
  sharp corners,
  frame hidden,
  boxrule=0pt,
  borderline west={2pt}{0pt}{ocre},
  colback={ocre!10},
  overlay={
    \node[left,inner sep=6pt,ocre,font=\small] (A) at (interior.east) {$\blacksquare$};},
  #1
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Informações}
\section{Conversa informal}

\begin{etapa}
Texto
\end{etapa}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: could you change your code so that "Passo 1.1.1" is displayed?

Comment: @LCarvalho: Why??? What is `1.1.1` supposed to be?

Comment: I changed this information in my question

Comment: @LCarvalho: Question change is not very popular here on TeX.SE, but it is very easy achieved here: `number within=section` instead of `number within=chapter` ...

Comment: I just realized that I asked the wrong one only when I saw your answer